# INDEX,MATCH exact match if not the closest match

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A20,MATCH(1,(F10=C2:C20)*(F11=B2:B20),0))
```

This gives me back the exact match. Now I need a formula that also gives me the closest match (if there's no exact match).

Comment: Change the `),0))` to `),1))`?  What do you mean "closest match"?

Comment: i have 3 criteria (DATE, PURCHASE ORDER and ITEM ). Based on the item number I need the formula to return the Purchase order that match (or closer to) the date and the item.

Comment: still not working

Comment: the last MATCH parameter defines the type of lookup.  `0` looks for an exact match and the data can be in any order.  `1` or `-1` looks for the closest match (which could be exact if there is one), but the data must be sorted appropriately for the choice (`1`: largest <= target with data in ascending order; `-1`: smallest >= target with data in descending order).

Comment: @ALVG,, better share some sample data and expected result, help us fix the issue in better way !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I do believe that, you are looking for this:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming your data is in Range `A4:C8`.
- `D2, D3, E2 & F2` are **`Criteria Cells`**.
- Array Formula in `F2` to find **Closest Date** 
  to Date in `D3` i.e. `(01/15/19)`.

  `{=MIN(IF(B$4:B$8>D$3,B$4:B$8))}`
- The Array (CSE) Formula in `E3`.

  ```
  {=INDEX(A$4:A$8,MATCH(1,(D$2=A$4:A$8)*(E$2=C$4:C$8)*(F$2=MIN(IF(B$4:B$8>D$3,B$4:B$8))),0))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- *With both Formula to `Find/Match of closest 
  Date` the Operator may me `>` or `<`, depends 
  on your need that, are you looking for closest
  match is `Greater or less` than `Date in D3`.*
- Finish above shown Formula with 
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- DATE Format is `MM/DD/YY`.
- *Adjust Cell references in the Formula as 
  needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Worthwelle,, keep asking ☺